# Copy External Folder to Target While Building Jar(Using Maven)

Tags: java, jar, build, maven-3, packaging

First of all sincere apologies if my question is duplicate, I tried searching but couldn’t find relevant answer to my question

Question: I am creating a Fat jar out of my project using Maven “maven-shade-plugin“, now addition to that I have another Config folder(having some .dll , properties, .init etc files) , which I am referring from project.

Now what I want is, somehow while jar creation(preferably at Maven Build Time),my “config” folder also get copied parallel to the jar.

Using : Maven 3.3.9

Current project Structure:

ProjectParentFolder
     --.git 
     --.idea
     --src
     --config
     --pom.xml

Desired output

TargetFolder
        --ProjectParentFolder.jar
        --Config

Note** If this requires to copy config folder to inside some src folder , I can do that ,but after build I want it to be outside jar(preferably parallel to jar).

Please advise, as I have to automate this process in TeamCity/uDeploy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a shell script which will copy jars from source folder to the folder where it is required.

You can define all required jars in a text file.
Script will read required jars from file and copy it to destination folder.

Comment: Appreciate yor answer, But not sure if we can checkout from GIT using Shell, and over that its kinda messy approach to checkout one place and then copy using shell script to target, as in that we need to maintain server lists as well.

Comment: Just mention the parent folder which contain jars. It will work if jar is in sub directories or at more depth. Not sure about git

Answer (score 0):

maven-shade-plugin is mostly used to package uber-jar. I would advise to use maven-assembly-plugin instead. You can configure your config folder (using fileSet element) anywhere you would like it to in assembly.xml. For example:

```
   <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/Config</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>...</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

[maven-assembly-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-assembly-plugin)[jar](/questions/tagged/jar)[packaging](/questions/tagged/packaging)